# Custom binary crossentropy loss in keras that ignores columns with no non-zero values

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, casting

I'm trying to segment data where the label can be quite sparse. Therefore I want to only calculate gradients in columns that have at least one nonzero value.

I've tried some methods where I apply an extra input which is the mask of these nonzero columns, but given that all the necessary information already is contained in `y_true`, a method which only looks at `y_true` to find the mask would definitely be preferable.

If I would implement it with numpy, it would probably look something like this:

```py
def loss(y_true, y_pred):
    indices = np.where(np.sum(y_true, axis=1) > 0)
    return binary_crossentropy(y_true[indices], y_pred[indices])
```

`y_true` and `y_pred` are in this example vectorized 2D images.

How could this be "translated" to a differentiable Keras loss function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `tf`-compatible operations, via `tf` and `keras.backend`:

```
import tensorflow as tf
import keras.backend as K
from keras.losses import binary_crossentropy

def custom_loss(y_true, y_pred):
    indices = K.squeeze(tf.where(K.sum(y_true, axis=1) > 0))
    y_true_sparse = K.cast(K.gather(y_true, indices), dtype='float32')
    y_pred_sparse = K.cast(K.gather(y_pred, indices), dtype='float32')
    return binary_crossentropy(y_true_sparse, y_pred_sparse) # returns a tensor
```

I'm unsure about the exact dimensionality specs of your problem, but loss must evaluate to a single value - which above doesn't, since you're passing multi-dimensional predictions and labels. To reduce dims, wrap the return above with e.g. `K.mean`. Example:

```
y_true = np.random.randint(0,2,(10,2))
y_pred = np.abs(np.random.randn(10,2))
y_pred /= np.max(y_pred) # scale between 0 and 1

print(K.get_value(custom_loss(y_true, y_pred))) # get_value evaluates returned tensor
print(K.get_value(K.mean(custom_loss(y_true, y_pred))
>> [1.1489482  1.2705883  0.76229745  5.101402  3.1309896] # sparse; 5 / 10 results
>> 2.28284 # single value, as required
```

(Lastly, note that this sparsity will bias the loss by excluding all-zero columns from the total label/pred count; if undesired, you can average via `K.sum` and `K.shape` or `K.size`)

Comment: I did a few changes to work with the dimensions I utilize, but that did worked as intended, thank you!